# how to avoid empty string while updating user form fields in the database using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i'm new to spring with hibernate.after user loggedin i've a requirement to update the username,password,emailId when ever user like to change those fields.but here user may change any field for example he can change emailId and he left password and username empty strings...but in the service i want to update only which fields he give values in the database if he leaves any field empty string i want to avoid that field(but it is updating empty string in the database).i'm not sure all the time which field he wants to change i.e.  all fields or any of them.anyone can suggest me how to fulfill this requirement. thanks in advance.

Here's the jsp file:

```
  <%
  String path=request.getContextPath();
  %>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`enter code here`
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="<%=path %>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>

   <body>
  <form action="modifyUser.htm" method="get">
   <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
  class="fields">
 `enter code here`<tr>
   <td width="33%">User Name <span class="star"></span></td>
  <td width="67%"><input name="userName" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Password</td>
   <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="35">Email ID </td>
  <td><input name="emailId" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="left"><input type="image" src="<%=path %>/images/update.png" height="2 5" 
        `width="65" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
       </form>
       </body>
         </html>
```

here the main controller:

```
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/modifyUser.htm")
    public ModelAndView updateUser(@RequestParam String userName,@RequestParam String password,@RequestParam String emailId,HttpSession session)throws Exception{
        User user=null;
        try{
            user=(User)session.getAttribute("userSession");
            if(userName.equalsIgnoreCase(currentUserName)){
                System.out.println("i'm in same username case");
                user.setUserPassword(password);
                user.setUserEmailId(emailId);
                userService.updateUser(user);
                return new ModelAndView("user_management","message","user_modified");
            }else if(userService.isUserNameValid(userName)){    
                System.out.println("here username also changing 2nd case");
                user.setUserName(userName);
                user.setUserPassword(password);
                user.setUserEmailId(emailId);
                userService.updateUser(user);
                return new ModelAndView("user_management","message","user_modified");
            }else {
                System.out.println("case failed to update user");
                return new ModelAndView("external2","message","invalid_username");
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("in updating a user with username:"+userName+" ",e);
            return new ModelAndView("error","message",e);
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more elegant ways to do what you are doing (like using spring's `form` element: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-formtaglib)

But for this code you have posted, you could do this:

```
if (org.springframework.util.StringUtils.hasText(password)){
    user.setUserPassword(password);
}
```

The same applies to other fields.

Comment: thank ur suggestion....here the validator implementation is i should throw an error but i dont want to throw an error i just want to omit that field from updation..i'm not sure how many fields will be updated always but if he leave any field empty i have to omit that field from updation...in this way i have to write so many if conditions with 3 fields

Comment: If you don't want to use sping's `form` element then adding an if statement around each of your `set` methods seems the only way to me. In this way, if the text field is not completed, the `user` field won't be updated and it will keep the value that it had when it was loaded from the session.

Comment: yes i'm also thinking that is only the solution..thanku for reply..have a nice weekend

Answer (score 0):

Simply load the fields that the user omitted from the database. Then you'd be free to store your whole (ORM mapped) domain object again.

Comment: thank u 4 ur suggestion...i'm not sure how many fields will be updated always but if he leave any field empty i have to omit that field from updation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use spring's inbuilt validator interface.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html

Comment: thank ur suggestion....here the validator implementation is i should throw an error but i dont want to throw an error i just want to omit that field from updation..i'm not sure how many fields will be updated always but if he leave any field empty i have to omit that field from updation.